# How to get a clip with the same aspect ratio and without losing quality

Tags: premiere, vegas-pro

orig.mod - properties:

```
Frame width 720
Frame height 576
Data rate 8900kbps
Total bitrate 9284kbps
Frame rate 25 frames/second

Audio
Bit rate 384kbps
Channels 2(stereo)
Audio sample rate 48kHz
```

I need a short clip of the above file, and tried using `Sony Vegas Pro 13` and `Premiere cc pr0 2015`. In both applications I choose to adjust resulting file to the original, especially regarding frame size and frame rate. Result is simmilar in both applications:

result.mpg (tried .mp4 and .wmv also)

```
Frame width 720
Frame height 576
Data rate 9500kbps
Total bitrate 9724kbps
Frame rate 25 frames/second

Audio
Bit rate 224kbps
Channels 2(stereo)
Audio sample rate 48kHz
```

Main specifications are the same, but playing both file, using `VLC` and `WMP` players, what I see is - `result.mpg` is much narrower than `orig.mod`. Height is the same. That means aspect ratio is changed.
Also, `result.mpg` has poor quality, comparing to original.

Any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check you pixel aspect ratio.  Its in the video settings in premiere.  My guess is its not matching the original file. Play around with the different settings.  Usually square pixels do it for me.

[Adobe Premiere Pro CC aspect ratio streched](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15122/adobe-premiere-pro-cc-aspect-ratio-streched)

Comment: It won't be square pixels here, since `.mod` files are SD format signals of certain old JVC/Canon cameras. So, either 1.092 for overscanned print or 1.06667 for full aperture.